# Troubleshoot sun-java6-jdk installation

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, java, jdk

1. Just finished a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10 on a new machine
2. I added the partner repository via ubuntu software center
3. I ran 'sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk'
4. I ran 'sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun' and got this error:

```
alex@alex-home:~$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

Double checking it failed, I am still on the JRE:

```
alex@alex-home:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
alex@alex-home:~$
```

Tried this too:

```
alex@alex-home:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java       63        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The JDK is not listed, but it is listed on disk:

```
alex@alex-home:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-java  java-1.6.0-openjdk  java-6-openjdk  java-6-sun  java-6-sun-1.6.0.22
```

**UPDATE:**

Installing plugin and fonts caused update-java-alternatives to stop complaining, but still no luck:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

Then:

```
alex@alex-home:~$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun 
alex@alex-home:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

**UPDATE 2:** Hmm, maybe its actually working? I thought "...SE Runtime..." meant JRE, but maybe its all good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SE Runtime means that you're running Java Standard Edition, rather than Enterprise Edition (AKA Servlets/JSP, which need an application server). You should be just fine with what you have installed right now! If you want to develop Java programs, just make sure that `javac` is installed on your system.

**EDIT**
Also, make sure that javac is being provided by java-6-sun, otherwise you'll probably be using the GNU Java compiler which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal try this command

```
javac
```

if you get output something like below then it means that you have java jdk installed.

sample output:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files 
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

You can also check the version by running

```
javac -version
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the output of your `java -version' command is generated by the java binary of sun-java6-jre package. So your installation is successful.